# Etale sheaf $\mu^{\otimes d}$

Tags: sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

I see everywhere the etale sheaf $\mu^{\otimes d}$, but I cannot see the precise definition.

Concretely, what is the sheaf $\mu_3 \otimes \mu_3$ over ${\rm Spec}\mathbb{Q}$, for example described as ${\rm Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^{sep}/\mathbb{Q})$ module?

I know that tensor of sheaf ${\cal F} \otimes {\cal G}$ is defined by the sheafification of the presheaf $U \to {\cal F}(U) \otimes {\cal G}(U)$ (over some ring sheaf), but I don't know $\mu(U)$ is module over what ring.

Here I recognize for example $\mu_3({\rm Spec} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}))$ is cyclic group of order 3.

Comment: Here we are just talking about abelian sheaves, in other word $\mu(U)$ is just an abelian group and the tensor product is over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Roland Then I thought $\mu \otimes \mu$ equals $\mu$ because its stalk is cyclic group, but I have read $\mu^{\otimes d}$ are different each other. So, I am missing something.

Comment: Two sheaves can have the same stalks without being isomorphic. This is the case here : they are both locally constant sheaves with stalks $\mathbb{Z/3Z}$, in particular, they are even locally isomorphic but not globally. If $G$ is a group and $V,W$ two $G$-modules then $G$ acts on $V\otimes W$ via $g.(v\otimes w)=(gv) \otimes (gw)$. Here $\mu_3$ is the multiplicative group $\{1,j,j^{-1}\}$ with the canonical Galois action, and $\mu_3\otimes\mu_3$ is the group $\{1,j\otimes j, j^{-1}\otimes j\}$ with the above action, which turn out to be trivial.

Comment: And since the action is trivial, $\mu_3^{\otimes 2}(\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic of order 3, while $\mu_3(\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial.

Comment: @Roland Thank you. I got it. So, the action of $g \in G$ on $\mu^{\otimes d}$ is equivalent to the action of $g^d$ on $\mu$.